# How to Solve Argument 2: cannot convert from 'Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel.DynamoDBOperationConfig' to 'Amazon.DynamoDBv2.AmazonDynamoDBCallback'

Tags: amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine, amazon-dynamodb

I am working in DyanmoDB.In My project i have to dynamically set the database name and i have to load the database dynamically. This is my code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Amazon.DynamoDBv2;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Amazon.DynamoDBv2;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Amazon;

namespace AWSSDK.Examples
{
public class HighLevel3 : DynamoDbBaseExample
{

    private IAmazonDynamoDB _client;
    private DynamoDBContext _context;

    public Text resultText;
    public Button back;
    public Button createOperation;
    public Button updateOperation;
    public Button deleteOperation;
    public string S_tablefieldset;
    string bookID;
    int bookID1 = 9;
    public string Email;

    private DynamoDBContext Context
    {
        get
        {
            if (_context == null)
                _context = new DynamoDBContext(_client);

            return _context;
        }
    }

    void Awake()
    {
        
        back.onClick.AddListener(BackListener);
        createOperation.onClick.AddListener(PerformCreateOperation);
        _client = Client;
        S_tablefieldset = "Orders";
        HighLevelTableExample.GetDynamoDbOperationConfig(S_tablefieldset);

    }

    void Start()
    {
        bookID = SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier;
        System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MONO_REFLECTION_SERIALIZER", "Orders");
        PerformCreateOperation();
    }


    public static DynamoDBOperationConfig GetDynamoDbOperationConfig(string dynamoDbTable)
    {
        Debug.Log("The Table name is " + dynamoDbTable);
        var tableName = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MONO_REFLECTION_SERIALIZER");
        Debug.Log("The Table name is" + tableName);
        DynamoDBOperationConfig config = new DynamoDBOperationConfig()
        {
            //    OverrideTableName =

            OverrideTableName = tableName
        };

        return config;
    }

      public void PerformCreateOperation()
    {
        Debug.Log(" I am in Perform Create Operation is working fine and good");
        Book12 myBook = new Book12
        {
            OrderID = bookID,
            OrderItem = 50,
           
        };

        // Save the book.
        var tableName = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TABLE_NAME");
        Context.SaveAsync(myBook, new DynamoDBOperationConfig {

      OverrideTableName = tableName });
                
    }
}
```

public class Book12
{

```
    [DynamoDBHashKey]   // Hash key.
    public string  OrderID { get; set; }
    [DynamoDBProperty]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [DynamoDBProperty]
   

}
```

}

While doing the above i received the error in

```
error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from
```

'Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel.DynamoDBOperationConfig' to
Amazon.DynamoDBv2.AmazonDynamoDBCallback'

How to solve the error.